# How to protect svelte component from outer css styles

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have page index.html which includes file styles.css (  .foo{width:100%; ..... and other styles} )
via

```
<link href="styles.css">
```

And also this page includes svelte application

Svelte application has component with same class name `.foo`

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<style>
.foo{background-color:red;}
<style>
```

Svelte render it into something like this

```
<input class="foo svelte-12sas231dad">
```

Is there any method to protect my component's input from outer css ?

For example something to make

```
<input class="foo-svelte-12sas231dad">
```

without outer `.foo` class or may be another decision ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to not use global styles that accidentally apply where you do not want them to. I.e. remove the rules or use very specific class names that will not accidentally be used in components. Everything else is just a workaround to a fundamental problem you will run into again.

Given that Svelte adds classes with hashes you could target the element using a different method, e.g. just the tag type (`input`) or some `data` attribute.

As far as I know the only way to really isolate the element from styles would be adding an `iframe` which is far from ideal.

Comment: Another way would be to add shadow DOM.

Comment: I thought that as well, but when I tried it the styles leaked in. Maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: @DaveS: Actually, it's just the other way around: Shadow DOM styles do not leak outside.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/)?
Perhaps you could use the [The CSS !important Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) in your Svelte component styles.
Better yet, why not just change the class names?

Comment: (Using `!important` is rarely a good idea and it only overwrites properties but does not prevent other properties from applying.)